# Trying to print a line from a text file with other information in the same line

Tags: printing, text-files

Im trying to take the first line from the text file and then print that line with some data next to it. Here is my code and what the text file looks like.

```
def main():
    file = open("votes.txt")
    lines = file.readlines()

    votes = 0
    count = 0
    count_all = 0
    line = lines[1]
    for i in line:
        if i == 'y':
            count += 1
            count_all += 1
            votes += 1
        elif i == 'a':
            votes += 1
        else:
            count_all += 1
            votes += 1
    print(lines[0]+':', (count/count_all), end='')




main()
```

and this is what the text file looks like:
Aberdeenshire
yyynnnnynynyannnynynanynaanyna
Midlothian
nnnnynyynyanyaanynyanynnnanyna
Berwickshire
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnynnnnnynnnnny

When I run the program i get this output:
Aberdeenshire
: 0.38461538461538464
For now all I need is for the Aberdeenshire to be in the same line as :0.3846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what language this is - Python? (not familiar with that really)...

I suspect the lines[] strings each have a carriage return on the end, so perhaps doing a strip() on them would remove this, something like this:

`print(lines[0].strip()+':', (count/count_all), end='')`

Comment: Yeah sorry its python, let me give that a try thanks.